# Will iPod touch 5th gen device with iOS 8.2 support apple iWatch

Tags: ios8, watchkit, ipod-touch, apple-watch

I had an iPod touch 5th gen device running on iOS 7.2, and i upgraded it to iOS 8.3. But the "Apple Watch" app which should come by default as i see in iOS 8.2 simulator, is not available in my device.

So, my question is, will my device support apple iWatch synchronisation ?.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple have clearly told us that the iWatch will only work with iPhones. There is no reason to think that any iPod can support it. The press release told us 
"Apple Watch is compatible with iPhone 5, iPhone 5c, iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 Plus running the latest version of iOS 8." (http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2014/09/09Apple-Unveils-Apple-Watch-Apples-Most-Personal-Device-Ever.html)

Comment: This nails it. Additionally if, after two OS updates containing the Watch app, you still don't have it - I'd take it as a sign it isn't going to happen.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer **YES**
Except old devices that wont support iOS 8.*
If there won't be official app for the sync like the one you showed, there will be community made one, be sure!